# Histogram bar hidden

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can not see the right-most vertical bar given the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,ytick style={draw=none},title={Redisuals Magnitude},
      xlabel={Iteration (k)},
      ylabel={$\|\rho_{k}\|_{\infty}$},
      yticklabels={,,},xticklabels={,,},ylabel style={rotate=-90},xmin=0, xmax=8]
\addplot coordinates { (0, 10) (1, 5) (2, 2.5) (3, 1.25) (4, 0.625) (5, 0.3125) (6, 3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How is it possible? How can I fix it?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145421/barchart-with-pgfplot-missing-bar